# instantiate a singleton class in instrumentation test makes another instance instead of using previous one

Tags: android, automated-tests, singleton, dagger-2, android-instrumentation

I'm working on instrumented test in android, I use Dagger to make a singleton instance from a class called PlugAndPlayInterceptor. this class helps me to set different interceptors based on test needs. I inject it in my test class, when I set the interceptor it is good, but when I need to call interceptor it is null because somewhere else it makes another instance and uses the new one. I made a sample project based on and put it [here](https://github.com/haniyehkhaksar/SingletoneInstrumentTestIssue). please check it, I will appreciate if someone helps me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is technically creating the component twice. You should omit the one in `SharedTabletSetup`.

For that, you need to do some changes. First, make `TestAppComponent` accessible from `TestApp`:

```
class TestApp : MyApp() {
    lateinit var component: TestAppComponent

    override fun initDagger() {
        component = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()

        component.inject(this)
    }
}
```

The last change would be to use the existing component to do the `inject`. So open `SharedTabletSetup.kt` and remove the following lines:

```
val appInjector = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder()
            .application(app)
            .build()
appInjector.inject(this)
```

Now instead, inject the dependencies using the main component:

```
(app as TestApp).component.inject(this)
```